# Resize and upload script taking too long

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, image-resizing

I'm using a script which resizes images client side before uploading them via Ajax to a PHP file. I am resizing images client side to reduce the power demand on the server. My script works but is taking too long to upload the image and I need help understanding why this is the case. The first part of the file asynchronously resizes the image. The second part encodes the resized image source to dynamically created hidden input and finally, Ajax uploads the dynamically created input value to a PHP file by using a timeout 3-second delay function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
    /* Upload Logo Image */
    $("#loader-wrapper").hide();
    $("#logo_image").change(function(){

        $("#ImgText").fadeOut(10, "linear");
        $("#loader-wrapper").css('background-image', 'none').fadeIn(200, "linear");

        const form = document.querySelector('#user_update_settings');

        form.addEventListener('change', async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get data URI of the selected image
        const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget);
        const photoField = formData.get('logo_image');
        const dataUri = await dataUriFromFormField(photoField);

        // Defines Resized image URL
        const imgEl = document.createElement('img');
        imgEl.addEventListener('load', () => {
            const resizedDataUri = resizeImage(imgEl, 600);

                // Deletes Previous Input
                var element =  document.getElementById('new_logo_image');
                if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null)
                {
                var elementExists = document.getElementById("new_logo_image");
                elementExists.remove();
                } 

                // Creates New Input
                var objTo = document.getElementById('LogoInputContainer')
                var image_input = document.createElement("input");
                image_input.setAttribute("name", "new_logo_image");
                image_input.setAttribute("id", "new_logo_image");
                image_input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                image_input.setAttribute("value", resizedDataUri);

                objTo.appendChild(image_input);
                
            });

        imgEl.src = dataUri;

        });

        // Resize Script
        function dataUriFromFormField (field) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            
            reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
            resolve(reader.result);
            });
            
            reader.readAsDataURL(field);
        });
        }

        function resizeImage(imgEl, wantedWidth) {
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            const aspect = imgEl.width / imgEl.height;

            canvas.width = wantedWidth;
            canvas.height = wantedWidth / aspect;

            ctx.drawImage(imgEl, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            return canvas.toDataURL();
        }
    });

    // Image Upload
 $("#logo_image").change(function(){
    setTimeout(() => {  
        
        if(window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob){
            if($(this).val()){

            // Checks File Extension
            var fileExtension = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp'];
            if ($.inArray($(this).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1) {
                alert("Only formats are allowed : "+fileExtension.join(', '));
                exit();
            }

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/logo_uploader",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: new FormData($("#user_update_settings")[0]),
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(response){
                        if(response.type == 'success'){
                            $("#loader-wrapper").fadeOut();
                            $(".logo_image_container").css("background-image", "url("+ response.logo_image +")");

                        }else{
                            $("#loader-wrapper").fadeOut();
                            $("#ImgText").fadein(10, "linear").text("+ response.msg +");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            } else {
                alert("Can't upload! Your browser does not support File API!</div>");
                return false;
            }
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

Client-side, my logo uploader validates the file type, deletes the previous image [if it exists] decodes the $request->new_logo_image and saves the file in the folder 'logos' and in a SQL database.

```
// User ID
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        // Reserved Goods
        $user = Users::where('id', $user_id)->first();

        // Path
        $FilePathDB = FilePathDB::first();

        // Path
        $file_path = $FilePathDB->public_img_path;
        $path = $file_path.$user->logo_image;

        // Deletes Previous Logo [If Applicable]
        if(file_exists($path)) {
            File::delete($path);
        }
        
        // Validates Extension
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'logo_image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg',
        ]);

        // Generates a Unique New Name 
        $new_name = 'logos/'.$user_id.trim($user->username).uniqid().'.jpg';

        // Uploads request Image if file does not exist
        if($request->hasFile('logo_image')) {

            $image =  $request->new_logo_image; // your base64 encoded
            $image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image);
            $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
            File::put($file_path.$new_name, base64_decode($image));


            // Logo Image Variable
            $formFields = array(
                'logo_image' => $new_name
            );

            // User ID Update
            $users = Users::where('id', $user_id)
            ->update($formFields);

                // If Successful
                $response = print json_encode(array(
                    'type'=> 'success',
                    'msg' => 'Logo Uploaded Successfully',
                    'logo_image' => 'storage/'.$new_name,
                ));  
            } else {
                
                // If unsuccessful
                $response = print json_encode(array(
                    'type'=> 'failed',
                    'msg' => 'Ooops, image upload unsuccessful. Please try again!',
                )); 
            }
```

Condensed HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="/user_update_settings" id="user_update_settings" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="logo_image" class="pointer UploadImgBtn transition">
<input class="DisplayNone" type="file" name="logo_image" id="logo_image" accept="image/*">
<a>Upload Image</a> 
</label>
</form>
```

On average, for a 3MB image, it takes 3 seconds for JS canvas to resize the image and 15-20 seconds to upload the already resized file - now between 40-50KB in size. Knowing the image has been resized, why does it take so long for my code to upload the resized image? Are there any loops I haven't considered running in the background which are consuming the client's resources?

Comment: `"The first part of the file asynchronously resizes the image "` - surely the upload cannot begin until the image is resized so doing this asynchronously ( or trying to ) seems to make no sense does it? Having tried running this ( after fixing several issues of missing html ) and adding some debug statements I noted that the upload portion seems to be invoked very early... what debugging have you done to resolve the bottlenecks?

Answer (score 0):

After much thinking, I have just found the solution. When I ran my Ajax script I was submitting the whole form to the server which included both the old and the new image. To reduce the data load, one can either put the hidden input into a new form or else specify the data which is to be sent to the PHP file.

Comment: You are using a `FormData` object as the payload so you can use the `delete` method to remove the original file. I wrote a version in vanilla js which was able to resize a 10mb file and upload in a little under 3s from start to finish and used the `delete` method within that. Relying upon the `setTimeout` though seems hacky '-)